# How to set the "encrypt" attribute on the root folder?

Tags: windows-7, efs

There is an "Encrypt contents to secure data" checkbox for every folder on the drive, except the root folder. It's accessible by right-clicking a folder, and selecting "Advanced" properties:

[image]

One of its effects is to make any new file in this folder be EFS-encrypted.

I want any new file in the root of my drive D:\ to also be encrypted. However, this checkbox is missing from the drive properties dialog. Is there any way to apply this attribute to the root folder, so that new files in the root get encrypted?

<sub>Before you bring up full-disk encryption, remember that the two have completely different use-cases, in particular full-disk encryption is more limited in terms of what's possible with regard to multi-user environments.</sub>

Comment: Be sure to [backup your EFS](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/back-up-efs-certificate) certificate or you will have no way to recover your data in the event of a windows re-install.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `cihper d:\ /e`.

`cipher /?`:

> Displays or alters the encryption of directories [files] on NTFS partitions.

`/e`:

> Encrypts the specified files or directories. Directories will be
>   marked so that files added afterward will be encrypted. The
>   encrypted file could become decrypted when it is modified if the
>   parent directory is not encrypted. It is recommended that you
>   encrypt the file and the parent directory.